# What to do with my question on Right-to-Repair?

Tags: discussion

I've asked the following question: [How would 'Electronics Right-to-Repair' legislation affect Electrical Design?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/454396/199402)

When I posted this I felt it was extremely applicable to electrical design. My intention was to find out what types of technical design changes would need to occur in order to accommodate this law. I thought this *should* be a fairly un-opinionated question with citation to IEEE or other design standards. I'm not looking to start a debate or open a forum question.

However, I received a pretty mixed opinion on the question. It was put on-hold almost immediately, and still is, but it is currently sitting with 4 up-votes, 4 votes to reopen, 1 vote to delete. One user thinks it is extremely appropriate, the other thinks it is completely off-topic. So I'm lost, is it on topic or not? I have read the help page but I get stuck on the fact that it uses words like *feel* and *generally* to describe appropriate questions.

I tried narrowing the question down to just the fifth point in order to make the question less broad but I'm not sure where to go from here. Do I edit the question further and try to salvage it, does it need more (or less) context, or do I just vote to close it myself? I don't care much whether is stays open or gets closed at this point but I am looking for an opinion from the community and to educate myself further about EE.SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So looking at the question, I think it's on-topic, but it's *subjective and hypothetical*. The main reason I see it as hypothetical is because you are asking about a trade group's goals, not necessarily about enacted legislation. A similar hypothetical is "What if PETA had their entire agenda implemented in law?".

See the [help center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for further guidance.

Comment: That makes sense. With the context and framing of the question, it would make more sense to ask *after* the law would be enacted.

Comment: The problem is that it isn't a *specific technical question* - it's a policy question, or a "how to deal with this policy" question.  It's of course relevant to EE work, but not at all within the design scope of stack exchange